# Testing Eloquent Save method from a repository

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-4, eloquent

Given an eloquent repo that looks something like that.

```
 class PinRepo {
        protected $pinModel; 

        public function __construct( Model $pinModel )
        {
            $this->pinModel = $pinModel;
        }
        public function addPinToProject( $page_id, $inputs )
        {
            $pin = new $this->pinModel();
            $pin->fill($inputs);
            $pin->save();
            return $pin;
        }
    }
```

My first attempt was:

```
class PinRepoTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->modelMock = Mockery::mock( 'Pin' );
        $this->pinRepo = PinRepo( $this->modelMock );
    }

    public function testAddPinToPage() 
    {       
        $this->modelMock
            ->shouldReceive('fill')->with(["project_page_id"=>1])
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(Mockery::self())
            ->shouldReceive('save')
            ->once();
        $this->pinRepo->addPinToProject( 2, ["project_page_id"=>1]);
    }
}
```

But i get this error (Which kind of make sense)

> "Method ::fill() does not exist on this mock object"

**Given this setup, is there any way to get that test to pass ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i came up with:

```
class modelStub extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    static $methodCalls = [];

    public function fill(array $attributes)
    {
        self::$methodCalls['fill'] = TRUE;
        return $this;
    }
    public function save(array $options = array())
    {
        self::$methodCalls['save'] = TRUE;
        //dd($this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        //dd($name, $value);
        static::$$name = $value;
        return $this;
    }
}


class pageModelStub extends modelStub {
    static $project_guid = false;
}

    public function testAddPageToProject()
    {
        $modelStub = new pageModelStub;
        $this->pageRepo = new \Nota\Repos\PageRepo( $modelStub );
        $this->pageRepo->addPageToProject('project_guid', ['fds']);
        $this->assertTrue( $modelStub::$methodCalls['fill'] );
        $this->assertTrue( $modelStub::$methodCalls['save'] );
        $this->assertEquals( $modelStub::$project_guid, "project_guid" );
    }
```

**It seems hacky but at least I can test what matter to me on that method. Any improvements on this are very welcome.**